# Trying to Filter dataframe based on strings in a column R

Tags: r

The dataset is a list of injuries, my index is a series of words found in some of the injuries. I'd like to filter out all of the injuries in that column that do not contain any of the words from the index.

Here is what I'm starting with:

| x | index |
| --- | --- |
| torn meniscus | torn |
| sprained ankle | broken |
| broken leg |  |
| pulled hamstring |  |

This is what I'd like to have, based on matching the index with the column:

| x |
| --- |
| torn meniscus |
| broken leg |

As far as code goes, I'm stumped at how to include the whole list without typing out every index word to compare the x column against. I have:

```
    df %>% select(Date, Team, Injury, Players) %>%
      filter(str_detect(Injury, ))
```

I'd love to be able to do this in Excel, but unfortunately Excel doesn't take too kindly to 20,000+ rows being filtered with an index as large as the one I need.

Here is a more representative sample of my data, along with the full index. I removed one word from the index because of several cases of a minor injury description containing the word.

| Injury |
| --- |
| "placed on IL with torn meniscus in left knee (out for season)" |
| "placed on IL with sore right knee" |
| "placed on IL with left foot injury (out for season)" |
| "placed on IL with strained left hamstring (out for season)" |
| "returned to lineup" |
| "returned to lineup" |
| "activated from IL" |
| "placed on IL with right knee injury / conditioning" |
| "placed on IL with sprained right ankle" |
| "dislocated kneecap in left knee (out indefinitely)" |
| "activated from IL" |
| "placed on IL with sore right knee" |
| "placed on IL with sprained left ankle" |
| "placed on IL for personal reasons (out for season)" |
| "placed on IL with left leg injury" |
| "placed on IL with sore right knee" |
| "placed on IL with right calf injury" |
| "placed on IL with neck spasms" |
| "placed on IL with right groin injury" |
| "activated from IL" |
| "placed on IL with right hip injury" |
| "placed on IL with sore right knee" |
| "placed on IL with bruised right quadriceps" |
| "placed on IL with dislocated kneecap in left knee (out for season)" |
| "activated from IL" |
| "placed on IL with left calf injury (out for season)" |
| "placed on IL with strained left hamstring (out for season)" |
| "placed on IL" |
| "activated from IL" |
| "right knee injury (out for season)" |
| "placed on IL with bruised lower left leg" |
| "activated from IL" |
| "surgery on left knee to repair dislocated kneecap (out for season)" |

Index

[1] "fracture"   "broken"     "break"      "tear"       "torn"       "ligament"
[7] "tendon"     "ACL"        "MCL"        "meniscus"   "rupture"    "surgery"
[13] "bone"       "hernia"     "tendinitis" "chronic"    "dislocate"  "seperate"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could concatenate a complex regular expression from the unique values un column `df$index`.

```
library(tidyverse)

df <- tibble(
  x = c("placed on IL with torn meniscus in left knee (out for season)", "placed on IL with sore right knee", "placed on IL with left foot injury (out for season)", "placed on IL with strained left hamstring (out for season)", "returned to lineup", "returned to lineup", "activated from IL", "placed on IL with right knee injury / conditioning", "placed on IL with sprained right ankle", "dislocated kneecap in left knee (out indefinitely)", "activated from IL", "placed on IL with sore right knee", "placed on IL with sprained left ankle", "placed on IL for personal reasons (out for season)", "placed on IL with left leg injury", "placed on IL with sore right knee", "placed on IL with right calf injury", "placed on IL with neck spasms", "placed on IL with right groin injury", "activated from IL", "placed on IL with right hip injury", "placed on IL with sore right knee", "placed on IL with bruised right quadriceps", "placed on IL with dislocated kneecap in left knee (out for season)", "activated from IL", "placed on IL with left calf injury (out for season)", "placed on IL with strained left hamstring (out for season)", "placed on IL", "activated from IL", "right knee injury (out for season)", "placed on IL with bruised lower left leg", "activated from IL", "surgery on left knee to repair dislocated kneecap (out for season)"), 
  index = c("fracture", "broken", "break", "tear", "torn", "ligament", "tendon", "ACL", "MCL", "meniscus", "rupture", "surgery", "bone", "hernia", "tendinitis", "chronic", "dislocate", "seperate", NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA))

df %>%
  ##   In the next line we take all values from `index`, remove NA, 
  ##   and append into a regex with the OR symbol  ('|') separating strings.
  filter(grepl(pattern = unique(na.omit(df$index)) %>% paste0(collapse = "|"), 
         x = x)) %>% 
  select(-index) ## Here you remove the column index from the data frame
```

## Results:

```
# A tibble: 4 x 1
  x                                                                 
  <chr>                                                             
1 placed on IL with torn meniscus in left knee (out for season)     
2 dislocated kneecap in left knee (out indefinitely)                
3 placed on IL with dislocated kneecap in left knee (out for season)
4 surgery on left knee to repair dislocated kneecap (out for season)
```

Comment: That one didn't work for my dataset. If it helps at all I'm working with just over 27,000 rows of data, and have exactly 19 index words I'm trying to filter those by.

Comment: Well, it did work for what you posted. Could you perhaps post a representative sample of the injury column and the 19 cases of your index column?
Try the function `dput(your_data_frame)`,  it will help you share data in StackOverflow.

Comment: Added more representative sample of my data. If you need more let me know and I can expand. It's essentially 27,000 rows of those type of injury reports and I'd like to parse out the vast majority of them.

Comment: All right, I modified the example with your new data. Please let me know if it works now.

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is text matching, the `grep` function in base R.

```
data = c("placed on IL with torn meniscus in left knee (out for season)", "placed on IL with sore right knee", "placed on IL with left foot injury (out for season)", "placed on IL with strained left hamstring (out for season)", "returned to lineup", "returned to lineup", "activated from IL", "placed on IL with right knee injury / conditioning", "placed on IL with sprained right ankle", "dislocated kneecap in left knee (out indefinitely)", "activated from IL", "placed on IL with sore right knee", "placed on IL with sprained left ankle", "placed on IL for personal reasons (out for season)", "placed on IL with left leg injury", "placed on IL with sore right knee", "placed on IL with right calf injury", "placed on IL with neck spasms", "placed on IL with right groin injury", "activated from IL", "placed on IL with right hip injury", "placed on IL with sore right knee", "placed on IL with bruised right quadriceps", "placed on IL with dislocated kneecap in left knee (out for season)", "activated from IL", "placed on IL with left calf injury (out for season)", "placed on IL with strained left hamstring (out for season)", "placed on IL", "activated from IL", "right knee injury (out for season)", "placed on IL with bruised lower left leg", "activated from IL", "surgery on left knee to repair dislocated kneecap (out for season)")

index = c("fracture", "broken", "break", "tear", "torn", "ligament", "tendon", "ACL", "MCL", "meniscus", "rupture", "surgery", "bone", "hernia", "tendinitis", "chronic", "dislocate", "separate")

pattern = paste0(index, collapse="|")

result = grep(pattern, data, value=TRUE, invert=TRUE)
head(result)
# [1] "placed on IL with sore right knee"                         
# [2] "placed on IL with left foot injury (out for season)"       
# [3] "placed on IL with strained left hamstring (out for season)"
# [4] "returned to lineup"                                        
# [5] "returned to lineup"                                        
# [6] "activated from IL"
```

#### Explanation

You want to find elements from `data` that do not contain any string from the `index` vector.
We construct regular expression from the index vector that would do this match. This is done with the `|` symbol. Pattern `A|B` matches elements that contain either `A` or `B`. So we just connect the elements of `index` vector with the `|` symbol:

```
pattern = paste0(index, collapse="|")
```

Now, we will match this pattern with grep tell it to return the matched values:

```
grep(pattern, data) # returns indices
grep(pattern, data, value=TRUE) # return matched items
```

Now, you do not want matched items, but items that do not match. This can be simply done with the `invert` argument:

```
grep(pattern, data, value=TRUE, invert=TRUE)
```

This will return items that did *not* match the regex pattern.